# Entity Framework update model after drop table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm working on an application with EF 6.0.0.0 database first. When I create a table in the database and perform the Update model from the database, the table classes are created correctly in the edmx file, but when I discard the table in the database and perform the Update model from the database, the table's references remain in my code. This is my question: is there a way to drop the table and remove the references from that table in edmx file automatically?

Comment: If you're using a `.edmx` model file, then you're most certainly **not** using EF Core - removed  tag

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please specify the version of Entity Framework you are using.